# Are linear interpolation curves on Wasserstein spaces absolutely continuous?

Tags: curves, geodesic, optimal-transport, gradient-flows, wasserstein

Let $\mathcal{P}_2$ the space of absolutely continuous probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with finite second moment equipped with the $2$-Wasserstein metric.
Fix $\mu_0, \mu_1 \in \mathcal{P}_2.$
Let $T$ be the optimal transport map from $\mu_0$ to $\mu_1.$
It is well known that the geodesic curve $\mu_t = ((1 - t) \text{id} + t T)_\# \mu_0$ is absolutely continuous.

**I am wondering if the linear interpolation $\tilde \mu_t = (1 - t) \mu_0 + t \mu_1$ is absolutely continuous.**

Any reference would be helpful too.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

They are not. The reason is basically given in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4717214/boundedness-of-dfracw-2-mu-1-varepsilon-mu-2-mu-1-mu-1-varepsilon/4719496#4719496).

As a simple counterexample, consider $\mu_0=\delta_0$ and $\mu_1=\delta_1$. Then $W_2(\mu_0,\mu_t)=\sqrt t$ and hence $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{W_2(\mu_0,\mu_t)}{t}=\infty.$$

Hence $(\mu_t)_{t\in[0,1]}$ cannot be absolutely continuous. Here we have used the following result (see [Lectures on Optimal Transport](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-72162-6)):

[image]

Comment: Thank you! How about under the assumption that $\mu_0$ and $\mu_1$ have densities?

Comment: OK, having densities does not matter. There is still an example where this happens.

Comment: Are you aware of any example where $\tilde \mu_t$ is not absolutely continuous even though $\tilde \mu_t$ has a common support?

Comment: @Paruru What if we pick some measure $\mu\in\mathcal P_2$ such that the support of $\mu$ contains $0$ and $1$; then put $\mu_0=\frac 12(\delta_0+\mu)$ and $\mu_1=\frac 12(\delta_1+\mu)$?